# I am trying to write a shell program to execute more than one command at a time

Tags: shell, c

My Code

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() 
{ 

char * arg_list[3];
arg_list[0] = "ls";
arg_list[1] = "-l";
arg_list[2] = 0;

char *arg_list2[3];
arg_list2[0] = " ps";
arg_list2[1] = "-ef";
arg_list2[2] = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ // loop will run n times (n=5) 

       if(fork() == 0) { 
    if (i == 0){
    execvp("ls", arg_list);
}else if(i==1){
execvp("ps" , arg_list2);
}else if(i>1){
           printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
        exit(0); 
}
      } 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5) 
           wait(NULL); 

}
```

ME trying to modify it

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() 
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ // loop will run n times (n=5) 

       if(fork() == 0) { 
           printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid()); 
        execlp(argv[i],argv[i],argv[i+1],(char*)NULL);
        exit(0); 
      } 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5) 
           wait(NULL); 

}
```

-- NEED GUIDANCE AND UNDERSTANDING

I am trying to make my own tiny little shell program. When I run my first code works fine, runs all commands on the command line. But I cannot know and define all commands the user might enter. So i am trying to get a base  code which could run any commands single or multiple entered by user. I tried using `execlp` where it does not compile saying `argv` is not defined which is true as i don't want to specifically define it.

Comment: If you expect `argv[i]` to be some command line argument, you have to define it as an argument of your `main` function as usual. You should also check `argc` to make sure `argv[i]` or `argv[i+1]` exist. You probably mean something like `argv[2 * i]` and `argv[2 * i + 1]`. Your current code mixes up commands and their (single) argument.

Comment: Note that the array passed to `execvp()` is supposed to be NULL-terminated, which isn't the case in your example...

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make my own tiny little shell program. When I run my first code works fine, runs all commands on the command line. But I cannot know and define all commands the user might enter.

For sure.... A shell program purpose is basically:

1. Read user input
2. Execute user input
3. Return result of execution.

There's nothing in your code that read user input....

> So i am trying to get a base code which could run any commands single or multiple entered by user.

So read user input ;-)

> I tried using execlp where it does not compile saying argv is not defined which is true as i don't want to specifically define it.

For sure ... but how would GCC guessed that `argv[]̀  must be automaticallty filled with user input ? 
There's nothing automatic when coding in C language. You have to manage this manually.

Also, note that `argc`, `argv` et `envp` are usually reserved for `main()` function:

`main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`

So you may use something else to build your command array.

In pseudo code, what you must implement is:

```
quit=0
while (quit = 0) {
    command_to_run = read_user_input();
    if (command_to_run == "exit") {
       quit = 1;
    } else {
       execute(command_to_run);
    }
}
```

Some advices:

- Try to use more functions. For example, implement a `fork_and_run(char **cmd)` function to fork and then execute command provided by the user. Il will make your code more readable and easy to maintain.
- Read carefully manpages: everything you should know (like, for example, the fact that array provided to `execvp()` must be NULL-terminated) is written in it.
- Your debugging messages should be printed to `stderr`. The result of the command run must be printed to `stdin`, so use `fprintf()` instead of `printf()` to write to the correct stream.
- I would use a `#define debug(x) fprintf(stderr, x)` or something similar for debugging output so that you can easily disable later ;-)